# Is there an expression using the main constants of mathematics as result of the following infinite sum:

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty {{\pi^{k\over 2}}\over {\Gamma({k\over 2} +1)}}$$

I've found, that

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty {{\pi^{k\over 2}}\over {\Gamma({k\over 2} +1)}}$ = $e^{\pi} + 
2\sum_{k=0}^\infty {{({4\pi})^{k}k!}\over {(2k+1)!}}$

But does that help?

Comment: Well in fact you sum over the volumina of n-spheres. Just saying, don't know if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a closed form in terms of the [$\rm {erf}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) function

> $$ \operatorname{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^x e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt,  $$

as

> $$ {{\rm e}^{\pi }} \left( 1+{\rm erf} \left( \sqrt {
> \pi } \right)  \right) .$$